# How to mock firebase functions in cypress?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

We have not set up the API key of firebase for the test environment. So, code using firebase.auth() or initializeApp() fails due to invalid key. I want to mock firebase for test environments.

The line that is failing is:

```
const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(firebase.auth());
```

I am using 'react-firebase-hooks/auth' package.

In tests, I tried.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.stub(firebase, 'initializeApp');
  cy.stub(firebase, 'auth').returns([undefined, undefined, undefined]);
});
```